# How to extend CListView in order to remove extra yii added markup?

Tags: yii

The point is to remove from CListView render, those two divs:

```
<div id="yw0" class="list-view">
<div class="items">
```

I've been looking here:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php#L123

But I found nothing related with those two divs there.

Can anyone please share, what should we extend in order for make this a reality ?

Here's an update of the desired output:

```
<div>
  <article class="itemthing">
    list data
  </article>
  <article class="itemthing">
    list data
  </article>
  <article class="itemthing">
    list data
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: @mashingan: Because when you careful style your page, with semantic relevant containers, you wish not to have your code polluted with divitis markup like those two divs there. Unless they are useful in a way I can't see now... Can you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off extending from CListView itself, but write new implementations for `run()` [method in CBaseListView](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php#L123) and a new implementation for the `renderItems()` [method in CListView](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/CListView.php#L245), for example:

```php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CListView');
class MListView extends CListView{
    public function run(){
            $this->registerClientScript();
            // this line renders the first div
            //echo CHtml::openTag($this->tagName,$this->htmlOptions)."\n"; 

            $this->renderContent();
            $this->renderKeys();

            //echo CHtml::closeTag($this->tagName);
    }

    public function renderItems(){
            //this line renders the second div
            //echo CHtml::openTag($this->itemsTagName,array('class'=>$this->itemsCssClass))."\n"; 
            // copy original code from the function
            //echo CHtml::closeTag($this->itemsTagName);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Be aware that some of the default clistview functionality will not work with only this much, because the [jquery.yiilistview.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js) will not work without an id, that identifies this listview.

**Edit:**

From your updated question, you can do this, then:

```
<div id="some-id">
<?php
    $this->widget('ext.extendedwidgets.MListView',array(
        'id'=>'some-id', // same id you specified in the div
        //... rest of it
        'template' => '{items}', // as seen in the chat below
    ));
</div>
```

Comment: sure you can create it anywhere as long as yii can find the class, but i have done it in _protected/extensions/extendedwidgets/MCListView.php_ . Also be aware that the pagination will not work in ajax mode, out of the box, you'll have to modify the generated jquery/javascript also

Comment: thanks. Where can we then modify the generated jquery/javascript ? Care to share? I'm really sorry for all those questions, but this is something I wish doing for so long, and those divitis where always on the way... I would also like to learn why doesn't the ajax work if we remove those divs (or it doesn't work because we are extending it ?);

Comment: `$this->widgets('ext.extendedwidgets.MCListView',array(...))` . The jquery can be found in _zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js_ . the ajax doesn't work because the ajax update is done by the yiilistview.js, it looks for a div with an id and updates that div. so it doesn't work because we remove the divs. if you have a different container div (that contains this list), then you can pass that divs id to the jquery.

Comment: Often, we do have a natural container for those ListView Items. Can we just add the id he is expecting on that div and it will work? (this sounds kind of hackish) :D - The alternative would be to "extend" the  yiilistview.js but that doesn't seem nicer... because by extend we do mean copy/paste the file, and obviously that would not be up to date. :D

Comment: ok, can you tell me how your generated html should look like? is it : `<div id="somecontainer"><!-- listview --> </div>` ? better you tell me the exact output. there is a way to do it without having to copy yiilistview.js, so just tell me how you want to specify the view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16362/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-mem)