# Yii CListView with <ul> tag

Tags: php, html, listview, yii

I am trying to use a theme for my yii application. for listing the projects for portfolio section I'm using CListView. in the template it uses lists (`<ul>` and `<li>` tags) to show the portfolio elements, and since I didn't want to go through all files and jquery stuff I wanted to do the same. but CListView adds some div tags by default.. I need to know if there are any configurations for CListView to use `<ul>` tag instead of `<div>` and also set the class for it?

here is what I have:

```
<ul class="clearfix port-det port-thumb">
     <?php
          $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                      'itemView'=>'_view',
         ));
     ?>
</ul>
```

and in _view.php:

```
<li data-id="web print" class="clearfix">
  ...
</li>
```

and the HTML code I get in the end is something like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix port-det port-thumb">
   <div id="yw0" class="list-view">
      <div class="summary">Displaying 1-8 of 9 result(s).</div>
      <div class="items">
          <li class="clearfix" data-id="web print">
            ...
          </li>
      </div>
   <div>
</ul>
```

Update: and I need something like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix port-det port-thumb"> 
          <li class="clearfix" data-id="web print">
            ...
          </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so your final output html should be like what for the template to work? depending on that you might have to extend the listview, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12298898/720508)

Comment: actually i just realized that it could be simpler than extending, do you want summary div? do you want the outer div? do you want the pager div? (aside from your list)

Comment: there was no need for extending, with `itemsTagName` and `itemsCssClass` I could set the tag for the items to ul and also set the class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I can see there is no need to extend `CListView`. You can set its [itemsTagName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemsTagName-detail) and [itemsCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#itemsCssClass-detail):

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'itemsTagName'=>'ul',
        'itemsCssClass'=>'clearfix port-det port-thumb'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: was typing as i realized i was wrong before, sorry mahsa. remember to use `<li>` as you already have in your `_itemView`. however do note that the outer div will still be there in the final output