# YII CListView How to add id to itemwrapper

Tags: php, html, css, yii

In CListView there is a property called "itemsCssClass" which basically adds HTML class attribute to the Itemwrapper.

What if I like to add an ID or any other htmlOptions how will I do it on that wrapper..?

My code is :

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'viewData'=>array('x'=>''),
    'itemView'=>'_classifieds',
    'id'=>'boa_ads',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'test'
));
```

This code will produce this HTML:

```
<div id="boa_ads" class="list-view">
 <div class="summary">Displaying 1-4 of 4 results.</div>

   <div class="items"><!-- HERE ID LIKE TO ADD AN ID-->
     ----ITEMS GOES HERE ----
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the Yii's source:**

```
public function renderItems()
    {
            echo CHtml::openTag($this->itemsTagName,array('class'=>$this->itemsCssClass))."\n";
             .....
            echo CHtml::closeTag($this->itemsTagName);
    }
```

I just see `class` attribute is passed to the `itemsTagName` so you probably have to extend `CListView` to do it.

You can create a `CCustomListView` class (inside `application/widgets` folder) which extends from CListView and overwrite renderItems() function. **For example:**

```
<?php

Yii::import("zii.widgets.CListView");

class CCustomListView extends CListView
{

    public $itemsHtmlOptions;
    /**
     * Renders the data item list.
     */
    public function renderItems()
    {
        echo CHtml::openTag($this->itemsTagName, array_merge(array('class'=>$this->itemsCssClass), $this->itemsHtmlOptions))."\n";
        $data=$this->dataProvider->getData();
        if(($n=count($data))>0)
        {
            $owner=$this->getOwner();
            $viewFile=$owner->getViewFile($this->itemView);
            $j=0;
            foreach($data as $i=>$item)
            {
                $data=$this->viewData;
                $data['index']=$i;
                $data['data']=$item;
                $data['widget']=$this;
                $owner->renderFile($viewFile,$data);
                if($j++ < $n-1)
                    echo $this->separator;
            }
        }
        else
            $this->renderEmptyText();
        echo CHtml::closeTag($this->itemsTagName);
    }
}
```

In your view, you can use it like:

```
<?php $this->widget('application.widgets.CCustomListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=> 'your_data_provider',
    'itemsHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'color:blue', 'id' => 'your_id'),
    'itemView'=>'your_item_view',
    'template'=>'your_template',
)); ?>
```

So the style which in `itemsHtmlOptions` will be applied for the `listview`.

This link is also useful for you: [How to extend CListView in order to remove extra yii added markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298209/how-to-extend-clistview-in-order-to-remove-extra-yii-added-markup)

Comment: NO not the widget..what I mean in my question is the item wrapper .. specifically the DIV wrapping all of the item displayed.. same result as itemsCssClass property but this time the "id attribute" not the "class attribute".. I know that I can add an ID to the "widget" using the ID property.. But I am trying to add an id to the item wrapper..which in default has a class attribute of "items"..

Comment: I have updated the code to show the HTML and for a clearer idea