# Yii ClistView hidden div "keys"

Tags: yii

I used YII CListView and encoded true database id like PK column value before publish to HTML.

But also I find that CListView always shows these divs :-

1. div called "items" with all items and my artificial ids
2. hidden div called "keys" which nullifies step(i) since it dumps real
       ids / PK of table

Can we not disable CListView from showing hidden div **"keys"** in output HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I found out related post and looks like all required is to comment following line in CListView.run()

```
$this->renderKeys();
```

I hope this will not break pagination etc.

[How to extend CListView in order to remove extra yii added markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298209/how-to-extend-clistview-in-order-to-remove-extra-yii-added-markup)